# Stripe with Google App Engine - Upload image directly through browser using Javascript for Mananaged Account Identity Verification

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-app-engine, stripe-payments

Hi I've been searching for ages about how to upload directly from the browser, as is suggested in the case of using Stripe with Google App Engine at [this forum](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/issues/299).  Also the Stripe documentation suggests it is possible to upload directly from a browser as is suggested [here](https://stripe.com/docs/file-upload#using-your-publishable-key).

I have been trying with AJAX but from my effort and research it seems it is not possible to get the path to the local file because of security reasons. The code below shows the closest I've gotten, however I don't know how to upload an image through the browser without it touching the server. The console returns an error of "Invalid file: must be uploaded in a multipart/form-data request".

Next I will try using Jquery Form Plugin, however I don't know if I will have any success with that.

```
    var formData = new FormData($('#theHTMLForm')[0]);
    var sendarray={purpose:"identity_document", file:formData};
    sendarray=JSON.stringify(sendarray);

            $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'https://uploads.stripe.com/v1/files',
        data: sendarray,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer STRIPEPUBLISHABLEKEY"
        },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
            alert('success');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('error');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  How do I upload an image via javascript to a remote location - in this case https://uploads.stripe.com/v1/files?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a very kind person on [this forumn](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/issues/299), I was able to make it work!!  I'll copy the answer here just in case anybody comes by looking for the same answer.

HTML

```
<div>
<form method="post" id="fileinfo" name="fileinfo" ajax="true">
    <input type="file" id="file-box" name="file" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</div>

<div>
    <div id='label-results'>...</div>
    <pre id="upload-results"></pre>
</div>
```

And Javascript

```
$('#fileinfo').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = new FormData();

    var publishableKey = 'pk_test_***';

    data.append('file', $('#file-box')[0].files[0]);
    data.append('purpose', 'identity_document');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://uploads.stripe.com/v1/files',
        data: data,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + publishableKey
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#label-results').text('Success!');
        $('#upload-results').text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3));
    }).fail(function(response, type, message) {
        $('#label-results').text('Failure: ' + type + ', ' + message);
        $('#upload-results').text(JSON.stringify(response.responseJSON, null, 3));
    });

    return false;
});
```